# Angularjs Using ng-class with ui-grid component

Tags: angularjs

I'm having difficulty trying to get this working. I have a grid being generated with data from my db and one of columns i targeted its specific value by assigning it to a ng-model called "hasError1" and another assigned by ng-model to "hasError2". I'm trying to do an ng-class if they are different to give it a specific css class. Here is my code. This ui-grid is in my controller class.

```
 cellTemplate: '<div ng-model="hasError1"></div>'

cellTemplate: '<div ng-model="hasError2" ng-class="{\'amount-error\': hasError1 != hasError2}" </div>'
```

I put my condition for ng-class to be ng-class="{amount-error: hasError1 != hasError2}"

amount-error is a css class that i have which i set the border to be

```
border: 1px solid red;
border-right:none;
border-left:none;
```

I have also tried this below but that didn't work.

```
ng-class="{1 : \'amount-error\'} [grid.getCellValue(row, grid.columns[index+12]) != grid.getCellValue(row, grid.columns[index+2])]"
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. And what is the exact problem? Is the bindings work? Is the second cell getting the class?

Comment: Hello Mosh Feu, thanks for replying back. It doesn't execute anything my row is still being displayed but no css is being applied even though hasError1 is not equal to hasError2.

Comment: Is the row has the class `amount-error` I'm trying to understand if the problem is with the angular part or the css part. What is the chance that you can create a [runnable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/863110) (it can be simpler example that just reproduce the issue - you can fill the data hardcoded).

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide exact code since some of it is confidential. :/ am I doing my ng-class expression correctly??

Comment: Actually yes, but you are not closing the second div. Add `>` after `ng-class="{\'amount-error\': hasError1 != hasError2}"`. Probably it's not the problem..

Comment: I do have it closing just scroll in my question you'll see its closed.

Comment: Here is your html: `<div ng-model="hasError2" ng-class="{\'amount-error\': hasError1 != hasError2}" </div>` The start tag is not closing. `>` is missing.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. It still didn't work

Comment: I have also tried this below but that didn't work.

    ng-class="{1 : \'amount-error\'} [grid.getCellValue(row, grid.columns[index+12]) != grid.getCellValue(row, grid.columns[index+2])]"

Answer (score 1):

The grid has its own isaloted scope, so you need to use

> grid.appScope

to access your application scope

For Example:

```
cellTemplate: '<div ng-class="{\'amount-error\': grid.appScope.hasError1 != grid.appScope.hasError2}" </div>'
```

or

```
cellTemplate:'<div ng-class="{\'amount-error\': grid.appScope.hasErrorFunc()}" </div>'

$scope.hasErrorFunc = function(){
     if(comparisonValue1 != comparisonValue2){
          return true;
     } else{
          return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for commenting on this post. its greatly appreciated. I tried your answer and it still didn't work. I didn't get no error but it didn't apply the css \'amount-error\'  if they weren't equal.

Comment: This is what I have cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ui-grid-column-align-right" ng-model="hasError2" ng-class="{\'amount-error\': grid.appScope.hasError1 !== grid.appScope.hasError2}" ng-click="grid.appScope.comparison(grid.getCellValue(row, grid.columns[index+2]), grid.getCellValue(row, grid.columns[index+12]))">{{grid.getCellValue(row, col) | currency:grid.appScope.uiCulture.currencySign:2}}</div>'

Comment: what is the value of hasError1 and hasError2?

Comment: i did ng-model for that specific cell template to be either hasError1 or hasError2. so for the cell amount I wrote an ng-model = "hasError2" but I don't think that works because I passed it in a function in ng-click but it didn't print out anything.  The only way I can get the values I want is doing this ng-click="grid.appScope.comparison(grid.getCellValue(row, grid.columns[index+2]), grid.getCellValue(row, grid.columns[index+12]))

Comment: ng-click="grid.appScope.comparison(grid.getCellValue(row, grid.columns[index+2]), grid.getCellValue(row, grid.columns[index+12]))" .      that gets my the values I want but i can't write those values inside a ng-class and compare them to see if they are equal or not. don't know why.

Comment: U can use COL_FIELD for example  '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ui-grid-column-align-right"  ng-class="{\'amount-error\': grid.appScope.hasError1 !== COL_FIELD}" ng-click="grid.appScope.comparison(grid.getCellValue(row, grid.columns[index+2]), grid.getCellValue(row, grid.columns[index+12]))">{{grid.getCellValue(row, col) | currency:grid.appScope.uiCulture.currencySign:2}}</div>'

Comment: COL_FIELD gets the current value. and when I tried grid.appScope.hasError1 !== COL_FIELD which aren't equal it didn't work. For example if i pass COL_FIELD and grid.getCellValue(row, grid.columns[index+2])) to a function and console log them I get the two values I want in a ng-click but when I do in a ng-class the comparision of those two values nothing happens.

Comment: use a function in ngclass and return true or false depends on your condition, i edited the answer, please refer above.